# How to use managed identity with Bridge to Kubernetes?

Tags: visual-studio, kubernetes

Has anyone managed to use managed identity with Bridge to Kubernetes?

I've been reading these articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/managed-identity?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/overview-bridge-to-kubernetes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/configure-bridge-to-kubernetes

but I cannot get this to work

```
enableFeatures:
    ManagedIdentity
```

I think there may be a documentation issue because it refers to both `KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml` and `KubernetesLocalConfig.yaml`

I've tried both names. If I put the above yaml in KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml I get a yaml serialization error. If I put it in KubernetesLocalConfig.yaml it doesn't seem to do anything so I suspect KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml is the correct name, but I can't find any details of the correct yaml other than on the "Use managed identity with Bridge to Kubernetes" page linked above.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out by decompiling the extension. It is a documentation issue.
The correct file name is indeed `KubernetesLocalProcessConfig.yaml`

and the below yaml will work (note the **-** was missing in the docs)

```
version: 0.1
enableFeatures:
  - ManagedIdentity
```